# How to destroy every screen currently open in the program using a button

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm creating a programming project which will simulate bacteria using matplotlib with a Tkinter GUI. Once the user has logged in there are 2 options. One is to continue to the main part of the program and the second option is to quit the program. I am wondering how to, once the "Quit" button has been pressed, to close the whole program.

I have tried destroying each screen using the .destroy() command which is currently open however I get multiple error messages and I'm not sure as to why this is wrong.

```
def shutdown():
    screen.destroy()
    screen2.destroy()
    screen3.destroy()
    screen6.destroy()
    screen7.destroy()
    screen8.destroy()

def session():
    global screen8
    screen8 = Toplevel(screen)
    screen8.title("Dashboard")
    screen8.geometry("400x400")
    Label(screen8, text = "Welcome to the Dashboard").pack()
    Button(screen8, text = "Simulate Bacteria", command = simulate_bacteria).pack()
    Button(screen8, text = "Quit", command = shutdown).pack()
```

---

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\aliso\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\aliso\Desktop\CompSci Project\BacSim.py", line 15, in shutdown
    screen2.destroy()
  File "C:\Users\aliso\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2305, in destroy
    self.tk.call('destroy', self._w)
_tkinter.TclError: can't invoke "destroy" command: application has been destroyed
```

Comment: If my answer works for you, please mark it as an accepted solution so other users know this problem has been solved (instead of just seeing that one answer was posted, whether or not it actually works). If my answer does not work for you, please comment letting me know the error my code gives you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it is because you are using `Toplevel`, so once the root window (`screen`) is destroyed, all the other windows also get destroyed.

Your function should look like this:

```py
def shutdown():
    screen.destroy()
```